# Search bar behavior inside Navigation Bar is inconsistent in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios13, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to include search bar inside the navigation bar through navigation item of the view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Sticky Section Headers"

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController()

    setUpNavBarAppearance()
}
```

This view controller has a collection view and when user taps on a cell in the collection view, i am pushing the a new instance of same view controller(demo purposes) on to the navigation stack..

The behavior for the search controller has been inconsistent between the two view controllers. For the first/root view controller, the search bar shows up by default, but for the second view controller that is pushed on to the navigation controller, the search is hidden by default until user scrolls down.. I would like keep the search appearance behavior consistent across both the screens..

I am aware of the `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` setting to false would keep the search bar visible all the time, but i want to hide the search bar while user is scrolling.

Is there anyway to get the consistent behavior?

Here is the gist file, if you like to try the code:
https://gist.github.com/prasadpamidi/829e636d4697fda025bb0795ee81e355

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried searchController.isActive = true/false?

Comment: Setting isActive on UISearchController will present search view controller... I don’t want to present search controller upon pushing the view Controller... I just want to make the search bar visible in the navigation bar like it does in the root view controller of the navigation controller..